# Count the number of rows in each group

Tags: sql, codeigniter

Using CodeIgniter's Active Record class and MySQL, I have a table of posts with `user_id` and various other fields, and I want to count how many posts each user has made. I could get rows where `user_id = $whatever` and count the number of results, but I'd have to loop through every `user_id` and use that `count_all_results()` query over and over for each one.

There must be a better way! If every field just had a field with a `1` in it, I could `select_sum` up that field and get a count. But that seems dumb.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using active record should be:

```
$this->db->select('field1, ... ,fieldn, count(1) as number_elements_of_row');

$this->db->group_by(array('field_group_1', ... ,'field_group_n'));

$result = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

so `$result` will have what you need!